# Powershell running from SQL scheduled job not writing to my log file

Tags: sql, powershell, sql-job

I am writing to a log file using the following command in powershell

```
$ThisException = New-Object System.ExecutionEngineException "Big fail!" 

Out-File -FilePath c:\sixcel\GRLog.txt -Append -InputObject $ThisException
```

When I run powershell script in VSCode, it works perfectly.  When I run from SQL Job, I get nothing.  I'm pretty sure it is a permissions issue.  I added full access to Everyone on that folder but that didn't help

```
PS C:\Users\Deb Kelly> get-acl c:\sixcel

    Directory: C:\

Path   Owner                     Access
----   -----                     ------
sixcel DESKTOP-6OLLP6P\Deb Kelly Everyone Allow  FullControl...
```

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to solve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: When you run some thing from sql,it uses sqlserver service account credentials,try running vscode using sqlserver credentials to see if this is the case.I am not talking about folder permissions

Comment: [ExecutionEngineException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.executionengineexception?view=netframework-4.7.2) is obsolete. First off, try writing a simple string into log. If that doesn't work either, it might be permission issue. If it does, there might be something about the exception that masks the IO attempt.

Comment: I removed the ExecutionEngineException and wrote a simple string.  Still doesn't work.  I don't know how to run vscode using sqlserver credentials.  I'll look online to see if I can figure that out.

Comment: @TheGameiswar - I think the issue is likely that the service account needs access.  Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Check sql server service account and provide access